# masm.exe doesn't work

Tags: assembly, masm

To not make a short story long, my teacher makes us use a MASM.EXE executable to assemble .asm files. She says the software has problems in Windows Vista and Seven, but not in XP. I have seen it work in many computers (using masm xxx.asm or debug), but in my machine (running XP SP3 as the others) it just does nothing.

I know that MASM.EXE is older than computers and even dinosaurs, but I need to use it (and not ml.exe, for example) because my school is so hardcore (and stupid).

tl;dr, when I run either 'debug' or 'masm xxx.asm' masm.exe does nothing.

Thank you very much in advance!

[image: After masm temp.asm it should make a .obj and a .lst files]

Comment: "It does nothing" is quite possibly the least helpful description of a problem. Does it give you a return code? What is it? Does it run when you use "/help" (or equivalent)? Etcetera, use your imagination.

Comment: I know it's not helpful, that's why I don't know what to try. I just input the line in cmd and nothing happens (no error, no .obj file, nothing). Sorry for not being able to describe it enough, I'll add a screenshot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, I have a fully up-to-service XP and it runs `debug` just fine. Well, it painfully forces the window to 80x25 while it's running and changes my prompt back to the short-file-name version on exit for some bizarre reason, but it certainly *runs!*

I can't test `masm` itself since it's not installed but first things first. Make sure you're running the right thing:

```
for %i in (masm.exe) do @echo. %~$PATH:i
```

and see what it comes back with. Also make sure you execute:

```
masm.exe xx.asm
```

to ensure there's no `bat` or `cmd` files getting in the way. If necessary, use the entire path to run it:

```
c:\full\path\to\masm.exe xx.asm
c:\windows\system32\debug.exe
```

You could also try running it in something like DOSBox which would be a far more primitive (`masm`-friendly) environment.

Failing all that, you have two problems. The first is the technical one which we're trying to fix, the second is a social engineering one.

Tell your educators *right now* (and back it up with something written down) that the tools they have given you are not working on your system despite the fact you meet all their criteria.

They do have a responsibility to provide you with workable tools and, even if they don't care, they at least know of the problem which may mitigate any problems you have down the track.

Comment: http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/3433/sshot23o.png
Nothing worked, I'm going to try DOSBox. Thank you very much for your reply ;__;

Comment: DOSBox worked, thank you so very much! Also, I'm sorry if my original post didn't provide enough info (I just realized I have -3 votes), it was certainly not my fault, since I couldn't get anything back from the process ;__;